# react-scroll target element not found

Tags: reactjs

I have a `Navbar` React component with a `Link` component which needs to scroll down to `Section` component when clicked. I have implemented `react-scroll`, however, when I click on the `Link` component, I get `target element not found` in the browser console.

The Navbar component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, animateScroll as scroll, scroller } from "react-scroll";

class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="section1" activeClass="active" spy={true} smooth={true}>
              Section 1
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

And the App.js file:

```
import React from "react";

// Styling
import "./styles/App.css";

// Components
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import SectionOne from "./components/SectionOne";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <SectionOne id="section1"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I used [this repo](https://github.com/jamesqquick/React-With-Smooth-Scrolling) as a reference, however, things don't work. What have I missed here?

Comment: Could you also share `SectionOne`? My guess is that he `id` prop is not forwarded to the actual DOM element

Comment: Turned out that was the case. I have posted the solution below.

Answer (score 5):

I have implemented a div inside of the SectionOne component

```
<div id="section-one-wrapper">Section One content...</div>
```

and then specified that id in the `Link` component:

```
<Link to="section-one-wrapper" activeClass="active" spy={true} smooth={true}>
    Section 1
</Link>
```

and it worked.